# Automate the boring stuff - extracting weather data with JSON & API

Tags: python, json, list

trying to work through the example of downloading forecasts from openweathermap.org as laid out in automate the boring stuff, but I'm having some issues. The service seems to be no longer included in the free subscription and if I download what is included I receive a key error. You can see the assignment toward the bottom of chapter 16:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter16/

I tried to adapt the code to the info available for free, but I really don`t understand w = weatherData['list']. What does that do? When I print: weatherData = json.loads(response.text), the result is as follows:

{'coord': {'lon': -0.1257, 'lat': 51.5085}, 'weather': [{'id': 803, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'broken clouds', 'icon': '04d'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 296.2, 'feels_like': 295.87, 'temp_min': 294.35, 'temp_max': 297.64, 'pressure': 1020, 'humidity': 50}, 'visibility': 10000, 'wind': {'speed': 2.57, 'deg': 240}, 'clouds': {'all': 55}, 'dt': 1694696224, 'sys': {'type': 2, 'id': 268730, 'country': 'GB', 'sunrise': 1694669592, 'sunset': 1694715572}, 'timezone': 3600, 'id': 2643743, 'name': 'London', 'cod': 200}

That is a dictionary. Is the code trying to convert it to a list? I do understand that after that we are trying to access certain parts by index, but "w" doesn`t work when I run it :(

Code:
w = weatherData['list']

During execution:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\andrea\mu_code\16_delete.py", line 21, in 
w = weatherData['list']
KeyError: 'list'

```
#! python3
# 16_getOpenWeather.py - prints the weather for a location 

# obviously not the real AppID ;-)
APPID = '12345'

import json, requests

location = 'London, UK'

# Download the JSON data from OpenWeatherMap.org's API
url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%s&APPID=%s' %(location, APPID)
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

# Load JSON data into a python variable
weatherData = json.loads(response.text)
print(weatherData)

# Print weather descriptions
w = weatherData['list']
print('Current weather in %s: '  % (location))
print(w[0]['weather'][0]['main'], '-', w[0]['weather'][0]['description'])
```

Comment: Your code is trying to access the 'list' key in the dictionary `weatherData`. However, `weatherData` doesn't have such a key, hence the KeyError. Available keys are 'coord', 'weather'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the example `json` data in `weatherData` you provided:

```
{'coord': {'lon': -0.1257, 'lat': 51.5085}, 'weather': [{'id': 803, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'broken clouds', 'icon': '04d'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 296.2, 'feels_like': 295.87, 'temp_min': 294.35, 'temp_max': 297.64, 'pressure': 1020, 'humidity': 50}, 'visibility': 10000, 'wind': {'speed': 2.57, 'deg': 240}, 'clouds': {'all': 55}, 'dt': 1694696224, 'sys': {'type': 2, 'id': 268730, 'country': 'GB', 'sunrise': 1694669592, 'sunset': 1694715572}, 'timezone': 3600, 'id': 2643743, 'name': 'London', 'cod': 200}
```

then it should be:

```
print(weatherData['weather'][0]['main'], '-', weatherData['weather'][0]['description'])
```

Outputs:

```
Clouds - broken clouds
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. You are right, the example in the book had 'list' in the output, hence this had nothing to do with creating a list. Sorry for the silly question, but it's hard  to follow examples that no longer work as described in the book without having a solid coding background. Your answer fixed the code and now the output is as it should be in the book :)